# Angular merge routes of child modules

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I am dividing my angular application into modules. For a module i have a view component and an edit component. The view components have their own url (e.g. '/users').

The edit components have a common parent url (e.g. '/admin/users').

```
 - UserModule
     - UserPageComponent ('/user/:username')
     - UserEditComponent ('/admin/user/:username')
 - GroupModule
     - GroupPageComponent ('/group/:groupname')
     - GroupEditComponent ('/admin/group/:groupname')
```

This does work and the urls are accessible.

If i look at the routes with augury i see that angular defined each '/admin' route as a separate route:
(3 admin routes with 1 child each)

```
- Root
    - Admin
        - Users
    - Admin
        - Groups
    - Admin
        - Permissions
```

But because of this the wrapping admin component is reloaded every time a user switches between a pages (resetting the menu state in the admin component).

Is it possible to define these routes like this?
(1 admin route with 3 children)

```
- Root
    - Admin
        - Users
        - Groups
        - Permissions
```

currently i define the routes in each submodule using this code (Replacing `Users` for each other module).

```
export const routes: Routes = {
  path: 'admin',
  component: AdminComponent,
  children: [
    {
      path: 'Users',
      component: UserEditComponent
    }
  ]
}];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)]
})
export class UserRoutingModule{}
```

And in the main routing module i just do:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot([])],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

i tried setting `onSameUrlNavigation` to `'ignore'` on the forRoot() call but unfortunately this didn't change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have and **AdminModule**, and inside this module inject your child modules (with their own routing)

For example I have a main app routing that load 2 lazy modules:

- **Authentication**, here I have a routing for register and login (both components)
- **Dashboard** (Admin), inside here I have another modules such as ClientModule and ProductModule wich are display in a `outer-outlet` inside dashboard component that also contain a sidenav and a toolbar.

[image]

> **OBSERVATION**:
>
> I would advice to use lazy modules at some routes for clean code, independency at unit testing and improve app performance.

[image]

I have this example at my github repo, if you have some questions or suggestions Im available to listen: https://github.com/danidelgadoz/ngx-admin

Comment: Hey, 

So then if i have a UserModule with an UserPageComponent ('/user/:username') and a UserEditComponent ('/admin/user/:username').

And a GroupModule with an GroupPageComponent ('/group/:groupname') and a GroupEditComponent ('/admin/group/:groupname'). Do you mean that i then should separate the view and edit components and make an AdminModule where i only include the edit components? (i also added the modules to my question, they are a bit easier to describe there)

Comment: Exactly, in that way when you move from one route to another the admin component will be static and only the router-outlet will change

Comment: Thanks after changing to explicit import and then it worked , But without explicitly loading why is it not working , isn't that us something suppose to work.

Answer (score 0):

To define routes like

```
Root - Admin - Users
             - Groups
             - Permissions
```

for Angular will be something like

```
Root - Admin - Users
     - Groups
     - Permissions
```

So in your app.routing.module.ts define the routes normally.

```
export const routes: Routes = {
  path: 'admin',
  component: AdminComponent,
  children: [
    {
      path: 'Users',
      component: UserEditComponent
    }
  ],
  { path: 'groups' component: GroupComponent},
  { path: 'permissions' component: PermissionComponent}
}];
```

Comment: Thank you, but i actually want to preserve the '/admin/' for all modules. I've updated my 'diagrams' to hopefully make it a bit clearer